# How can I apply AutoGenerateColumn to apply DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate in a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, datagrid

for an overview, an MVVM project in built in WPF.

Basically in my xaml, I have a datagrid bound to a dataview.  When my service populates the dataview I get a dynamic table with an arbitrary number of columns.

For each column in the datagrid, I have created a headertemplate which contains a combobox which is bound to an `Observable<Dictionary<string,BusinessEntity>>` object as its item source in the xaml.  Figuring out the combobox is another issue but I am trying to just populate data grid first, then worry about binding the combobox correctly.

anyways the only solution I have somewhat though of was to turn on autogeneratecolumn and then replacing all the headers with a combobox in the codebehind, but then I have issues trying to bind the combobox in the codebehind correctly and it doesn't feel MVVM if I have to create all those comboboxes there.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [AutoGeneratingColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event to customize the auto generated column's header template.